# Login to website with redirection using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, authentication, web-scraping, www-mechanize, webautomation

I know it sounds like a question which was already asked on forum ,however I believe that I have a slightly different scenario here..

I try to use Perl to log on to a web site which requires authentication. I already realized that the most convenient tool to accomplish this task is to use WWW::Mechanize module where it is quite easy to fill in forms and submit them.

In my case, I encounter the following difficulties:

1. it seems that there is no "form" which related to the fields I want to fill. Instead, the fields are wrapped in a table `<table></table>`.
2. The button itself seems to launch some javascript which I know is not supported by the        Mechanize module. However, just to test the behavior of this page, I disabled the javascript in my Chrome browser and still I was able to click on the button and login to the site. So I assume that javascript is not a must here.
3. I use the following code and it seems that it doesn't matter what details(user/pass) I enter, for some reason I always follow the "Success" scenario and receive "Login successful!":

   ```
   my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    cookie_jar      => {},
    autocheck       => 1,
    onerror         => \&Carp::croak,);

   # Login Form
   my $response = $mech->get($url);
   if (!$response->is_success) {
       die "Login page unreachable $url: ",  $response->status_line, "\n";
   }

   $mech->field('Email', $Email);
   $mech->field('Password', $Password);
   $response = $mech->click();
   if ($response->is_success) {
       print "Login Successful!\n";
   } else {
       die "Login failed: ",  $response->status_line, "\n";
   }
   ```

As a result, the running of the script seems to be successful however when I assume that I already logged on and try to obtain any data from the site, I see (in sniffer) that I am being continuously forwarded to the "Register" page.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I have realized how to solve this problem. I used Wireshark sniffer to analyze the difference between HTTP headers which were sent when using browser and headers which were created by the mechanize object. I found out that mechanize generated "Connection" header included "TE, close" value, while browser issued "Connection" header with "keep-alive" value in it. Moreover, browser generated request included additional "Keep-Alive: 115" header. I manually added these headers to my mech object as follows:

```
  $mech->add_header(
  "Connection" => "keep-alive",
  "Keep-Alive" => "115");
```

This solved the problem and I was able to login successfully!

Thank you all for you contribution and help! It is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If it's not in a form tag then there's a submit button somewhere which is using a GET request to send all the variables to the same (most likely) URL.

Why are you trying to emulate using a browser to click the authentication button, is there some other hidden field or something that you need access to?

In my eyes, the best way is to find out the page that is actually authenticating the user and password and use a SSL POST request to that page.

If the page has something like:

```
<input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="password" name="pass" />
```

Send over a HTTP POST request to whatever the login page is (likely the same page if no <form> is defined). The POST variables will be user=$value and pass=$other_value.

Comment: Hi Dave and thank you for your reply!

Can you please suggest how can I find out which page is performing the authentication?

And just to clarify.. 
You mean that I can just send a regular  HTTP POST request instead of clicking the button? Does it have the same effect as filling in the inputs and clicking an actual button? If yes, I afraid that I somehow missing the need in WWW::Mechanize module...

Thanks again!

Comment: Eugene, clicking a submit button on a web form sends either a POST or a GET request depending on the method="" line in the <form> tag. If there's no <form> tag it's sending a GET request (default) so just grab all the inputs from the page and send them. Here's some good reading on GET vs POST and <form> tags: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Answer (score 2):

When you check if `$response->is_success` you just checking that the target site response without any HTTP errors to you. But instead **you need to check if response page contain some text**. For example, "Auth ERROR!" etc.

If the target site work with disabled JavaScript than this is not an issue.

Try to add x and y (coordinates of the mouse pointer) to the data submitted to the form (some site check this info).

You can use some HTTP traffic monitoring tool to check what data your browser sends to the target site (i use Firefox HTTPFox extension for that) and make a same request via WWW::Mechanize.

Also, WWW::Mechanize don't need cookie_jar. It process cookies by default.

Try this code:

```
$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit_form(
    form_name => 'aspnetForm',
    fields => {
        'ctl00$cph1$lg1$txtEmail' => $login,
        'ctl00$cph1$lg1$txtPassword' => $password,
    },
    button => 'ctl00$cph1$lg1$btnLogin',
);
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comments! I used the HttpFox add-on (it is very useful indeed). However I am not sure I understand what I see there.. When I choose the POST Request and choose the "Headers" tab, I see only the regular headers and cookies (which you said are handled automatically anyway). I found some more data in the "POST data" tab, including the names and values of the submitted fields. I also see some parameters with hash data in them: __VIEWSTATE,__PREVIOUSPAGE,__EVENTVALIDATION. Can you give me a clue as how to use it to create relevant POST with Mechanize? Thanks!!

Comment: __VIEWSTATE is usually hidden form field, so you don't need to worry about it (Mechanize will process it automatically). Did you try to submit cursor coordinates to the target site? Can you give me your target site URL so i can check it?

Comment: Hi and thanks again! I didn't try the coordinates yet since I was not sure how to obtain the correct button location. What I was planning to do is use "Inspect Element" feature in Chrome to find the coordinates. And it can be great if you could take a look at the site, maybe I'm missing something there. The url is [link](http://www.eoddata.com). Thanks!

Comment: Hi @gangabass. Thanks for your post. I tried to use the code you've provided, but unfortunately I get similar results. I have performed a deeper analysis using sniffer and I found 2 issues: 1. I see that after the initial post, I receive a redirection resp(302) and I am not sure it is handled properly.
2. There are few differences between the requests I send using Mechanize and those issued by FireFox. For example with FF, I have  headers: "Keep-Alive:115" and "Connection: keep-alive" and with Mechanize "Connection: TE, close". Maybe this is the reason I am failing with the authentication?

Comment: Try to add this line (after creating your $mech object): `    $mech->agent(
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18"
    );`